# It does not appear to be a standard CRC. Can I know this formula in reverse?

Tags: math, crc

Interpreting binary protocols for older equipment. I interpreted most of the contents of the protocol, but the last error detection part seems to be in crc16 form, but it does not seem to be standard.
Can you reverse this if it's not standard?

This is the data source from packet capture.

1. 01 24 01 ff 00 04 52 4e 00 00 **eb ec** 04
2. 01 24 01 ff 00 04 46 56 00 00 **fe 2e** 04
3. 01 24 01 ff 00 04 52 55 00 00 **f9 89** 04
4. 01 24 01 ff 00 04 52 54 00 00 **f0 c0** 04

ex 1)
01 : STX

24 : ??

01 : ID1

ff : ID2

00 : ??

04 : DataLength

52 55 00 00 : Command

eb ec : **crc16 ? anything else?**

Can you give me a hand?

> For your information, we looped polynomials from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF. With some calculations correct, the other data was not the desired crc.

> Random substitution script on this site : http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html

```
let order = $('input[name="order"');
let polynom = $('input[name="polynom"');
let init = $('input[name="init"');
let fxor = $('input[name="xor"');
let data = $('input[name="data"');
order.value = 16;
polynom.value = 0001;
init.value=0000;
init.fxor=0000;
let result = $('input[name="result"]');
let cnt = 0;
data.value ='%01%ff%00%04%52%4e%00%00';
let itv= setInterval(()=>{
    polynom.value = (cnt++).toString('16');
    compute();    
    if(result.value.startsWith('F0C0')){
        console.log('polynom:'+polynom.value);
        clearInterval(itv);
    }
});
```

Somebody help me!

Comment: Does not appear to be a CRC, period.

Comment: So, is there any way to know what that is?

Comment: 4 packets are not enough, just enough to say not CRC. Can you post more to better identify potential correlation?